# How to achieve this complex layout with CSS?

Tags: css

I've this (apparently) simple layout :

[image]

There is a lot of technique out there, but I can't find one that will fulfill all the requirements. Could you point me to te correct direction ?

**Edit :** I need my layout to be 100% of it's parent, and to fall back to divs (or td's) one under this other on small screens. [See my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/matthieubrunet/gkmmhwvq/2/)
And I will need gutters.

#### table

Piece of cake, of course, thanks to rowspan and colspan. And it's easily fluid. But, can't use media query to change the display for small screens.

**Edit :** actually, media query works with td's. I just set it as `display:block` on small screens, and here we go. [This is my working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matthieubrunet/gkmmhwvq/2/). But you know, "table is bad"...

#### float

I didn't even try. Do you think I should have ?

#### imbricated div's

It's not possible to imbricated this. I could use absolute positionning, but it wouldn't be fluid anymore

#### flexbox

Each time I try to use flexbox, it ends with a headache. But if I'm not wrong, we can't have rowspan and colspan at the same time.

#### css grid layout

It's the graal. Maybe it's metaphysic.

Comment: I'd vote for absolute positions for all + media queries for responsiveness.

Comment: I would use float on all, and absolute position on the blue one..

Comment: It can be done quite easily entirely with floats and no relative or absolute positioning. Why not have a go?

Comment: I don't understand why somebody voted my question down...

Comment: Because it's asking for opinions and so is off-topic for Stack Overlfow.

Comment: Well, maybe my title is wrong, but I ask for code solutions, not opinions...

Comment: The you're asking for too much. Pick one method and get help on that,,,otherwise the question is too broad and **still** off-topic.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but before I ask, I didn't know what  method investigate. So I asked to point me one method that could fulfill my needs. It's not broad as my layout is very specific (in my opinion, but I may be wrong). Anyway, I changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say float's is the easiest way, with `position:relative` and `top:-x%` (x based on % of boxes) on the blue one.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="red portrait"></div>
    <div class="green landscape"></div>
    <div class="yellow landscape"></div>
    <div class="blue portrait"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}

.container div {
    float:left;
}

.red {
    background-color:#e23812;
}

.yellow {
    background-color:#e2df00;
    clear:both;
}

.green {
    background-color:#28a837;
}

.blue {
     background-color:#224395;  
    position:relative;
    top:-20%;
}

.portrait {
    width:40%;
    height:60%;
}
.landscape {
    width:60%;
    height:40%;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k23rfvqm/1/)

Comment: I may have not be very clear : I need it to be responsive. See my comment above.

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/k23rfvqm/1/) *change the container's width and/or height to see it in action.*

Comment: Yes indeed, it works well. I forgot to specify that the white block on the middle is also a block. I succeeded to add it with the blue one absolutely positioned, but may be there is a way to achieve it only with float ?

Comment: Glad I helped out. Float is my most used method when positioning elements.

Comment: I'm having a weird behavior... may be you can help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995609/css-float-weid-behavior

Answer (score 1):

My two cent on this issue, using some flexbox and without float.

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74cspL45/2/).

Here would be the step by step approach:

1. we create a container box that will handle our design (200px by 300px)
2. we use flexbox to create a 2 by 2 box (without the hole in the middle). Flexbox helps to create two rows, each divided into two columns just using `flex-flow: row wrap` (it will distribute divs in a row, and when it's too narrow it wraps the rest into a new line).
3. In our case we need to fine-tune `.landscape` and `.portrait` divs to fit desired proportions (40% and 60% width or height depending on the case). As 60% + 40% will always occupy 100% of a row, we are assured that the `flex-flow` property will wrap the other two divs into a new line, itself fitting 100% as well.
4. At this stage, the shape looks pretty good except for the blue div which is not correctly aligned with the yellow one.
5. we just correct above point by applying basic re`position`ing to the blue div

Comment: Smart, but the white color of the central block mislead you : I need it to be a regular block too !

Answer (score 0):

I just did it here is a fiddler link

https://jsfiddle.net/48L7btg6/5/

I separated it into two parts:
 - Part 1: the red and the green figure
 - Part 2: the green and the blue figure
got the Part 2 as

```
position:absolute;
left:150px(or whatever you want);
top:0px(just in case?);
```

And you're done

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be responsive. So it has to remain at 100% of the parent, and to fall back to div's one above this other on small screens.